# How to set new folders inherit folder permission in Docker volume on Mac

Tags: php, macos, docker, docker-machine

I am using Docker-machine on Mac for a PHP application.
My code is shored in mac, and shared to docker-machine as volume.

This is my docker-compose.yml

`app:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html`

My PHP application will create a folder in the shared volume and write some files in it.
The shared volume is set to permission 777 on mac (which I know I shouldn't do it, but I cannot solve the problem even with this)
After running the application, I got `mkdir(): Permission denied`.
The newly created folder is in permission drwxr-xr-x, so my application cannot write any file in it.

Is there anyway to set the new folders to inherit folder permission from its parent?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at http://docker-sync.io - using unison as strategoy, you can actually properly map the uid on the user in the container, removing any issues with permissions.

Comment: I am using docker-sync with WSL and the performance has been great. However I have dynamically created bash scripts that are temporarily put on my shared volume but the permissions don't stick so they fail to execute when the time arrives.